# Dependent Column in DataGrid not change when some other changes ( WPF C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have bunch of `Order`s in my application which i want to show in datagrid and edit their attributes inplace. There is a class named `Order` which weight attribute depends on `Item.Weight` and `Order.Count`. In the datagrid to which `ObservableCollection<Order> Orders` is bound, I want to change rows in place. The `City` and `Item` values are changing but `Weight` does not update in UI when `Item` or `Count` change.

--MyViewModel

```
public class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _OrderId;

    public int OrderId
    {
        get { return _OrderId; }
        set
        {
            _OrderId = value;
            RaiseProperChanged();
        }
    }
    private City _City;
    public City City
    {
        get { return _City; }
        set
        {
            _City = value;
            RaiseProperChanged();
        }
    }
    private Item _Item;
    public Item Item
    {
        get { return _Item; }
        set
        {
            _Item = value;
            RaiseProperChanged();
        }
    }
    private int _Count;
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _Count; }
        set
        {
            _Count = value;
            RaiseProperChanged();
        }
    }
    private int _Weight;
    public int Weight
    {
        get { return _Weight; }
        set
        {
            _Weight = value;
            RaiseProperChanged();
        }
    }
    public static ObservableCollection<Order> GetOrders()
    {
        var Orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
        return Orders;
    }
    public DateTime DateOfOrder { set; get; }
    public Order()
    {

    }
    public Order(int _id, City _cty, Item _itm, int _count)
    {
        OrderId = _id;
        _City = _cty;
        _Item = _itm;
        Count = _count;
        Weight = _itm.Weight * _count;
        DateOfOrder = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaiseProperChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }
}
```

}

--My View

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Orders"
              FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
              Margin="20,0,20,0"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              DataGridCell.Selected="DataGrid_GotFocus"
              CanUserAddRows="True"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              Height="250">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderId, 
                    Mode=TwoWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                Header="ردیف"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource BLotus}"
                                Width="70"
                                IsReadOnly="True"/>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding City, 
                    Mode=TwoWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                    x:Name="citytoadd"
                                    Header="شهر"
                                    Width="150"
                                    />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="محصول"
                                    x:Name="itemtoadd"
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Item, 
                    Mode=TwoWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                    Width="350" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Count, 
                    Mode=TwoWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                Header="تعداد"
                                Width="75"
                                />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Weight, 
                    Mode=TwoWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                Header="وزن"
                                Width="100"
                                IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

For example : when i edit a row in datagrid i want to update the entire attributes , but in this case i can change `Item`, `Count` and `City` of a `Order` but weight doesnt update.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Good job on your first question. You could try to make it more clear what you are having trouble with. Maybe try to recude the amount of code you have posted, as it is pretty hard to distill where the problem could lie. Also, please elaborate on where in the code the switching of fields should happen according to you, give an example of what you  would like to acchieve, and what is happening now.

Comment: Thank you so much . I'v applied some changes to my question.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the displayed `Weight` would be a calculated value from `Count * Item.Weight` and the user would never directly modify the `Weight` value? I'll assume it for now and write an answer for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to display a calculated `Weight` value based on other properties, you should change the following parts of your code:

Make the binding one-way, since the value will always be re-computed in source.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Weight, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Header="وزن"
                    Width="100"
                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Write the property as get-only calculation.

```
public int Weight
{
    get { return Item.Weight * Count; } // TODO: adjust if Item can be null
}
```

Notify for dependent changes in the source properties of your calculation. If `Item.Weight` could change within an item instance, you need additional handling.

```
private Item _Item;
public Item Item
{
    get { return _Item; }
    set
    {
        _Item = value;
        RaiseProperChanged();
        RaiseProperChanged(nameof(Weight));
    }
}
private int _Count;
public int Count
{
    get { return _Count; }
    set
    {
        _Count = value;
        RaiseProperChanged();
        RaiseProperChanged(nameof(Weight));
    }
}
```

Remove everything that accesses the `Weight` setter (for example in constructor).

See the following minimal working example for a calculated property. I rely on auto-generated columns in this case, but the same should be possible with hand written columns.

```
<Window
    ... your default generated window class, nothing special ... >
    <Grid x:Name="grid1">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Viewmodel itemtype definition with dependent property `Calculated`:

```
public class ExampleItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Number;
    public int Number
    {
        get { return _Number; }
        set
        {
            _Number = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Calculated");
        }
    }

    public int Calculated { get { return 2 * Number; } }


    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

MainWindow constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var data = new List<ExampleItemViewModel>();
    data.Add(new ExampleItemViewModel { Number = 1 });
    data.Add(new ExampleItemViewModel { Number = 2 });

    grid1.DataContext = data;
}
```

What should happen: the DataGrid autogenerates an editable column for `Number` and a read-only column for `Calculated`. Since the columns are autogenerated, the default behavior applies: when you change a number, the source will not be updated immediately, because the row is in edit mode. It will be updated after the edit completes (eg. you press enter or the row loses focus). As soon as the source is updated, the dependent `Calculated` column value changes to 2 times the `Number` value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've followed steps you said but did'nt work. i think because of i'm new to MVVM i cant figure it out. I found a way to solve it, assigning Weight whenever item or count changing :  
           `set{
                _Item = value;
                _Weight = _Count * _Item.Weight;
                RaiseProperChanged(); } 
            set
            {
                _Count = value;
                _Weight = _Count * _Item.Weight; RaiseProperChanged();
            }`

Comment: @Eti I added a small example, maybe you find it useful to learn about calculated columns and it may help you understanding why it didn't work out in your case.